# The requested captchaStyle 'yourFirstCaptchaStyle' is not defined in the botdetect.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, https, captcha, botdetect

I use angular-captcha with angular frontend and spring backend.

I did all the steps defined [here](https://captcha.com/angular-captcha.html#angular-java-spring-backend:springboot-autoconfiguration) but when I call

`my-api-endpoint/simple-captcha-endpoint?get=html&c=yourFirstCaptchaStyle` ws

it gives me the following error

> { "timestamp": "2021-02-08T00:37:14.011+0000", "status": 400, "error":
> "Bad Request", "message": "The requested captchaStyle
> 'yourFirstCaptchaStyle' is not defined in the botdetect.xml!", "path":
> "//simple-captcha-endpoint" }

here is my botdetect.xml file content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<botdetect xmlns="https://captcha.com/schema/java"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="https://captcha.com/schema/java
             https://captcha.com/schema/java/botdetect-4.0.beta3.7.xsd">

    <captchaStyles>
        <captchaStyle>
            <name>yourFirstCaptchaStyle</name>
            <userInputID>yourFirstCaptchaUserInput</userInputID>
        </captchaStyle>
    </captchaStyles>
</botdetect>
```

**I dont know why I get this error just when working on https domain, but not on http://localhost**

did I miss something ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
"BDC_configFileLocation", "/WEB-INF/classes/botdetect.xml");
```

The path `/WEB-INF/classes/botdetect.xml` worked for me